# Image's Exif orientation attribute got lost after multipart post through Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, image, orientation, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am uploading my image file to the server by using multipart post through **Retrofit**, I did not change the orientation of my image file before I upload it. After uploading the file, I try to download the image file from the server but unfortunately the image has no longer exif orientation attribute.

This is the part in my Activity that I uploaded the image file through retrofit:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new UrlConnectionClient())
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL).build();

    RetrofitService service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);

    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile(FileUtils.getFileContentType(file), file);
    service.postImage(Owner.getInstance().getCurrentPet().getPetId(),
    typedFile, message, new Callback<MyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(MyResponse myResponse, Response response) {
            String pictureUrl = myResponse.getPictureUrl();
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pictureUrl).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

I also tried to download manually the picture from the server and check its exif orientation attribute by implementing this code:

```
public int getImageRotation(ExifInterface exifInterface){
        int rotation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (rotation){
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotation = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotation = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotation = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                rotation = 0;
        }
        return rotation;
    }
```

The getImageRotation() method return 0 after checking the manually downloaded image file

Comment: You did not tell if the file length on server is the same as originally. And what is the length when downloaded again? Three values please.

Comment: 'I also tried to download manually the picture'. What ever you mean by 'manually'... show the code. Can you upload it 'manually' too?

Comment: 'manually' means downloaded in browser

Comment: it has the same length and witdh

Comment: The only thing that is change is that the orientation is removed @greenapps

Comment: `it has the same length and witdh`???? Files only have a length. Or size. The number of bytes of their content. No height or width. So please tell the three file sizes.

Comment: sorry typo error, i mean height and width.

Comment: Do not look at height and width as they will not change so quick. Look at the file size as i already asked you to do twice. Three values please.

Comment: sorry my bad, i found out that the raw image file is 1.4 MB is size, then the downloaded image is only 744KB

Comment: @greenapps our php developer said that the image uploaded will turned into a blob. I don't know if this is the cause of changing of image file size

Comment: Of course not. Putting bytes in a blob will not change the amount or values of the bytes. Ask the php man to log the amount of received bytes of the image. And just let him tell you the amount of bytes before and after blob.

Comment: the image length got smaller after blob.

Comment: Strange that you are not commenting yourself on that.